# Meteor Collection FS insert not working after removing insecure packages

Tags: templates, meteor, collections, insert, fs

As you can see from the heading I got a problem with my Collection FS after removing insecure packages.

I am using cfs:gridfs.

Removing packages: INSECURE, AUTOPUBLISH

My HTML

```
<template name="image_upload">
    <input class="fileinput btn" type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" {{disableButton}}>
</template>
```

In my Server publications.js

```
Meteor.publish("image_upload", function () {
    return Images.find();
});
```

My lib/collections.js

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
    stores: [
    new FS.Store.GridFS("images"),
    ],
    filter: {
        allow: {
            contentTypes: ['image/*']
        }
    }
});
Images.deny({
    insert : function() {return false},
    update : function() {return false},
    remove : function() {return false},
    // insert : function() {return false},
});
Images.allow({
    insert: function() { return true },
    update: function() { return true },
    remove: function() { return true }
});
```

And my event for the image upload

```
Template.image_upload.events({
    'change .fileinput': function(event, template){
        // console.log('abs');
        var username = Meteor.user().username;
        FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file){
            var fsFile = new FS.File(file);
            fsFile.username = username;
            fsFile.tweetkey = Session.get('tweetkey');
            Images.insert(fsFile, function(err) {});
        });
    }
});
```

My Packages

```
# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
# Check this file (and the other files in this directory) into your repository.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

meteor-platform
accounts-ui
accounts-password
msavin:mongol
cfs:standard-packages
cfs:gridfs
iron:router
mizzao:jquery-ui
mizzao:bootstrap-3
fortawesome:fontawesome
reywood:publish-composite
momentjs:moment
```

Would be nice if anyone can help me!

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: @Curtis there is no error message... btw i removed the plugin autopublish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting rules for `Images.deny({})` too. They will override your `allow` ones but as far as I know `deny` rules should be added first. On the documentation they mention:

> Meteor allows the write only if no deny rules return true and at least one allow rule returns true.

**EDIT**: After seeing you don't have any errors in your console, I think it's only a matter of subscriptions (removing `autopublish` will force you to subscribe for every route). Try changing your template and router like:

client\image_upload.html

```
<template name="image_upload">
  <input class="fileinput btn" type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" {{disableButton}}>

  {{#each images}}
    <div class="img">
      {{this.original.name}}
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

lib\router.js

```
Router.route('/', {
  name: 'image_upload',
  action: function () {
    this.render('image_upload');
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      images: Images.find({})
    };
  },
  waitOn: function () {
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('image_upload')
    ];
  }
});
```

In the future, try looking at https://github.com/meteorhacks/subs-manager for a better subscription manager, caching etc.

Comment: I add the deny rules above in my question but it still not works. when i add the autopublish package the upload works great but i don't want to use it

Comment: Can you provide the list you will find in `.meteor/packages`? Also, are there any errors showing up on your server's terminal? Anything on the browser's console?

Comment: I add the packages above. There is no Error showing in server's terminal or browser's console...

Comment: I have edited my answer with the right way to subscribe for `iron:router`.

Comment: Thank you! Works nice now! But how can i display the images ?

Comment: Take a look at [https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#display-an-uploaded-image](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#display-an-uploaded-image)

Comment: Yea i got it now! :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
Meteor.publish("image_upload", function () {
    return Images.find();
});
```

but "image_upload" is your template name, not your collection name. Your collection is called "images".

On the server you define which data (collections) you publish to the client side. Try this:

```
Meteor.publish("images", function () {
    return Images.find();
});
```

Comment: I add this too but it still not works... i will separate my question that you can understand the code easier

Comment: Now i get an error in the brower console: The provided value 'undefined' is not a valid enum value of type XMLHttpRequestResponseType.